# Replacing a Locked Excel File on Microsoft SharePoint using R and Microsoft365R

Tags: r, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, file-locking, microsoft365r

I am trying to replace an Excel file on Microsoft SharePoint with another local file using R and the [Microsoft365R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/index.html). The issue arises when the Excel file on SharePoint is open online by another user, which results in an error when attempting to delete it. I receive the following error message: "Locked (WebDAV; RFC 4918) (HTTP 423). Failed to complete operation. Message: The resource you are attempting to access is locked."

Here is the code I am currently using to delete and upload the file:

```
drv <- site$get_drive("My_drive")
drv$delete_item("Share_prova/mesos.xlsx", confirm = FALSE)
drv$upload_file("mesos.xlsx", dest = "Compartir_prova/mesos.xlsx")
```

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I have tried using the Microsoft Graph API package to obtain the lock status of a file on SharePoint before deleting it, but I haven't been able to find a suitable solution.
- I have also researched other functions or methods in the Microsoft365R package that might facilitate replacing a locked file, but I haven't found any relevant documentation.

**Specific Question:**

- How can I check the lock status of a file on Microsoft SharePoint before attempting to delete it using the Microsoft365R package in R?
- Is there a more elegant way to replace a file on SharePoint without encountering the locked file error?